# How to loop through table and update a column value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table `tFile` in my database, I want to loop through the table and update `filename` as shown in this example:

```
 id    fileId     filename
 -------------------------
 231    555        Null
 123    444        Null
 572    732        Null
```

I want to update the filename to be the `name(fileId)` as shown here:

```
 id    fileId      filename
 ----------------------------
 231    555        test(555)
 123    444        test(444)
 572    732        test(732)
```

I wrote a SQL script that update just one filename according to writing it manually but I need to update all filename using loop. I think I have to do nested loop one to loop through `fileId` and other to loop through `id`.

But I'm sorry I have no experience about this. I need help please.

```
update tFile
set filename = 'test'+ '('+fileId+')';
where id in (231)
```

Comment: You can use a while loop. were you are getting the filename could you please share the script so I can plan.

Comment: How I can do it, wihch condition I need to put?

Comment: You don't use loops in SQL, since it's set based. Simply skip the WHERE clause to UPDATE all rows.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't really store data calculated from other columns, because sooner or later you end up with data inconsistency. Either create a view, or have a _computed column_.

Comment: Please check this `UPDATE tFile
SET filename  =CONCAT('TEST(',fileId,')')`

Comment: You shouldn't handle loops by yourself, you should let the DBMS do it for you. SQL is not an imperative language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your expected output, I've created a sample table please have a look.

```
DECLARE @tFile TABLE
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    fileId    INT,
    filename NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @tFile VALUES(555,NULL),(444,NULL),(732,NULL)
SELECT *,CONCAT('TEST(',fileId,')') AS [FileNameUPdate] FROM @tFile
UPDATE @tFile
SET filename  =CONCAT('TEST(',fileId,')')

SELECT * FROM @tFile

/*Added tResultTable*/
DECLARE @tResult TABLE
(
    fileId    INT,
    filename NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @tResult(fileId,filename) --Insert query
SELECT fileId,filename FROM @tFile --Select query


SELECT * FROM @tResult
```

Output

[image]

Comment: How I can save the result data (the table efter modifing ) in a new table. I used this query but it show wrong. Create table tresult as select * from tFile. the error is (error syntax near select Edge_type or FILE_TABLE)

Comment: Please share the details I'll look into and let you update accordingly.

Comment: I would like the Select result move to a new table. I tested with Create table tResult as Select * From tFiles but I get error near by Select. I don't know why this error. Can you help me please?

Comment: Sure I'll update the answer please check.